# $_FILE['objectPhoto']['name']; returns empty

Tags: php, html

I included this HTML code inside a PHP variable in order to display it in a PHP page. After it is displayed successfully I was not able to send the uploaded image by POST method to "UploadObjPhoto.php" page. the name always shows an empty value. when I copy the code to a new php page it just works perfectly. Any ideas how to deal with this?

```
$resultDiv = "
<body>
    <div class=body id=Wrapper>
        <div id=second>
           <form id=upload action=UploadObjPhoto.php method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
           <input type=file name=objectPhoto><p>
           <input class=buttom name=upload id=submit value=Upload type=submit>
       </div>   
    </div>
</body>";
echo $resultDiv;
```

on UploadObjPhoto.php page:

```
$fileName = $_FILES["objectPhoto"]["name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["objectPhoto"]["type"];
echo $fileName;
echo $fileType;
```

Comment: Why don't you enclose property values in quotes? `id="upload" action="UploadObjPhoto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"` etc...  in ALL tags.

Comment: Like @AbraCadaver said, there should be quotes around property values. i.e. id='upload' action='UploadObjPhoto.php' method='POST'.... as well as name='objectPhoto' and so on for inputs too.

Comment: Actually the whole HTML code is inside double quotes and it works correctly in other parts of my program but anyway I have tried everything and didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure in your server in php.ini file: file_uploads = On? On UploadObjPhoto.php page use print_r and show what is there.

Comment: it shows an empty array

Comment: can't see a closing `</form>`